# Pull the shirt behind

Tags: sentence-construction

He was putting his shirt.

The shirt was stuck on his head.

He just pulled on the front.

> "Pull behind." (ommit "it" after pull)
>
> "Pull the shirt behind."

Do we need to say it in complete sentence as the second one？

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pull behind" is very strange-sounding.  "Pull it behind" is better, but still not something this native speaker would ever say, because you don't want him to pull the entire shirt behind his head.

Based on your statement "He pulled on the front", I think you mean  **"Pull on the back"**, but I would probably say **"Pull it over your head."**

Answer (score 2):

"Pull behind" is unclear. Do you mean this?

> Pull the back of the shirt down.